# Тоже самое для textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Скрипт:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[title].mi').bind({
        focus: function() {
            if ($(this).attr('title') == $(this).attr('value')) {
                $(this).attr('value', '');
            }
        },
        blur: function() {
            if ($(this).attr('value') == '') {
                $(this).attr('value', $(this).attr('title'));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Он сверяет значение поля value с title и если они равны, то при фокусе поле очищается. действует для инпутов с классом mi.

Вот пример:

```
<input type="text" value="Name *" title="Name *" class="mi" />
```

Можно ли тоже самое, только для textarea. Просто для textarea нет атрибута value. Поэтому  в html придется делать так:

```
<textarea name="" rows="10" cols="40" title="Nachricht *">Nachricht *</textarea>
```

Как быть с jQuery?

Помогите, пожалуйста. Будет хорошо, если это будет дополнение к первому скрипту, но можно два разных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например

```
<textarea name="txtArea" class="mi" rows="10" cols="40" title="Nachricht *">Nachricht *</textarea>
var textAreaValue = $("textarea[name=txtArea]").val();
alert(textAreaValue);

$(function(){
    $('textarea.mi').bind({
        focus: function() {
            if ($(this).attr('title') == $(this).val()) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        },
        blur: function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val( $(this).attr('title') );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: А что мне с этим делать? Как должно выглядеть в итоге? Я просто не очень понимаю в JS. И зачем alert?

Comment: пример)
тоже самое как и в инпут, только для получения значения используется метод val()

Answer (score 1):

Используйте html(). У textarea внутренности задаются, если следовать DOM, в node value (дословно - значение узла, т.е. innerHTML этого элемента, включая дочерние элементы).

```
$(function(){
    $('textarea.mi2').bind({
        focus: function() {
            if ($(this).attr('title') == $(this).html()) {
                $(this).html("");
            }
        },
        blur: function() {
            if ($(this).html() == '') {
                $(this).html($(this).attr('title'));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: а как это дело применить для textarea с классом mi2 ?

Comment: @inferus-vv, обновил

Comment: а если поле пустое, он не возвращает предыдущее значение (брать из title)

Comment: т.е. если напечатать текст, потом его удалить, то поле остается пустым